# Put image in a rounded CGRect

Tags: ios, swift, cgcontext, cgpath

I need to put a background image inside of a rounded CGRect.

I can make corner of the CGRect rounded using code below.

```
let cornerRadius = CGSize(width: 4.0, height: 4.0)
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: barRect, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner(rawValue: UIRectCorner.topLeft.rawValue | UIRectCorner.topRight.rawValue), cornerRadii: cornerRadius)
context.addPath(bezierPath.cgPath)
context.fillPath()
```

I can draw an image in the CGRect like below.

```
context.draw(image, in: barRect)
```

But, I cannot round the corner of the path since I have to use `fillPath()` and it makes the background as solid color.

Comment: All corners rounded or less than 4?

Comment: Just topLeft and topRight

Comment: Why are you using `fillPath()`?  Does `close()` not do what you need without filling the background?

Comment: I have tried `closePath()` also but not worked. I guess the problem is I use the not-rounded rect for drawing the image, but. I could not find any other way.

Comment: @sbekir - are you trying to generate a new `UIImage` with transparent Rounded Top corners? Or do you want to display an image in a `UIImageView` with Rounded Top corners?

Comment: I want to put the image as a background of the bars of the BarChart that's why I do not have `UIImageView` there. I have tried to draw the path in the context and fill it with image. Its working without rounding the corners of that `CGPath`. So a new `UIImage` with transparent Rounded Top corners can work I guess. But how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension:

```
extension UIImage {

    public func imageWithRounded(corners theCorners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let cornerRadius = CGSize(width: radius, height: radius)
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
        let img = renderer.image { ctx in
            UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: theCorners, cornerRadii: cornerRadius).addClip()
            draw(in: rect)
        }
        return img
    }

}
```

And use it like this:

```
guard let img = UIImage(named: "myImage") else { return }
let roundedImage = img.imageWithRounded(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 20.0)
```